# Using De Morgan's laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I can easily prove part (i) using double inclusion and could use the same method to prove part (ii).

But here it says, that I have to use part (i) and De Morgan's laws to prove it. I don't understand how I can do that.

3. (i) Let $A, B$, and $C$ be subsets of a set $S$. Write out a proof that

$$
A \cap(B \cup C)=(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap C) .
$$

(ii) Let $D, E$, and $F$ be subsets of a set $S$. Use (i) and De Morgan's laws to show that

$$
D \cup(E \cap F)=(D \cup E) \cap(D \cup F) .
$$

Comment: Try taking $A=D^c, B=E^c, C=F^c$ in (i) and apply de Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=D^c, B=E^c, F=C^c$ in (i). Then we have
$$D^c\cap (E^c\cup F^c)=(D^c\cap E^c)\cup (D^c\cap F^c)\,.$$
Now apply de Morgan to the brackets. We get
$$D^c\cap(E\cap F)^c=(D\cup E)^c\cup(D\cup F)^c\,.$$
Now apply de Morgan again:
$$(D\cup (E\cap F))^c=((D\cup E)\cap(D\cup F))^c\,.$$
Hence taking the complement of both sides, we get:
$$D\cup(E\cap F)=(D\cup E)\cap(D\cup F)\,.$$

Comment: Understood, Thank you so much

Comment: @ArhamMehta No problem, you can accept my answer by clicking the green check mark if this question is resolved